# Strain Energy in di-axial vs di-equatorial

Tags: organic-chemistry, cyclohexane

I am dealing with two conformations of *cis*-1,4-dimethylcyclohexane. One conformation is di-axial, and the other one is di-equatorial. Why does di-axial have higher strain energy. I would make sense if the molecule was 1,3-dimethylcyclohexane because then it would the steric hinderance that would cause higher energy. Is it similar with 1,4-.. conformation? If its not steric repulsion, what factors cause di-axial to have higher strain energy?

Comment: Di-axial and di-equatorial in *cis*-1,4-dimethylcyclohexane in a chair conformation?

Comment: Look at your molecule again. Are you sure you are not talking about *trans*-1,4-dimethylcyclohexane? In the *cis*-isomer both methyl groups must point in the same direction relative to the ring. That means one must be equatorial and one must be axial.

Answer (score 4):

**You can't have both in a chair conformation!**

1. If the methyl groups in 1,4-dimethylcyclohexane adopt a bis-axial orientation, they are *trans* and they stay *trans* after ring flip:
   [image]
2. If your 1,4-dimethylcyclohexane is *cis*-substituted the orientation of the methyl groups is axial and equatorial, respectively:
   [image]

Comment: They could be both equatorial in a boat or twisted configuration, though. Currently I am not too sure which is the thermodynamically most stable one.